# Django RestAPI Server can not POST to it from iOS App

Tags: python, ios, django, django-rest-framework, afnetworking-2

I'm making a simple Rest API Server.

Everything works fine. I have a model, a serialiser etc. When I browse to `localhost:8000/foobars/` I can get and post foobars, also `localhost:8000/foobars/1/` works fine. (POST from Browser works)

I have two models: Geopoint and FooBar.

Geopoint:

```
class Geopoint(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
```

FooBar:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    geo_location = models.ForeignKey(Geopoint, blank=False)  # required
    geo_fence = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)  # required
    registered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Serializer:

```
class GeopointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Geopoint
        fields = ('id', 'latitude', 'longitude')

class FooBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    geo_location = GeopointSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = FooBar
        fields = ('id', 'geo_location', 'geo_fence', 'registered', 'last_login')
```

views.py is looking like this:

```
"""
    GEOPOINT
"""
class GeopointList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Geopoint.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GeopointSerializer

class GeopointDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Geopoint.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GeopointSerializer


"""
    FOOBAR
"""
class FooBarList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = FooBar.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooBarSerializer

class FooBarDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = FooBar.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooBarSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^geopoints/$', views.GeopointList.as_view()),
    url(r'^geopoints/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.GeopointDetail.as_view()),

    url(r'^foobars/$', views.FooBarList.as_view()),
    url(r'^foobars/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.FooBarDetail.as_view()),
]
```

So when I trying to POST a new Geopoint in iOS using AFNetworking this code works!

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 @"latitude": @"50.1205530",
                                 @"longitude": @"8.6444050"
                                 };
    [manager POST:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/geopoints/"
       parameters:parameters
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Trying to POST a new FooBar I get a Error:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                     @"geo_location": @{
                                         @"latitude": @"50.1205530",
                                         @"longitude": @"8.6444050"
                                         },
                                     @"geo_fence": @"Frankfurt",
                                 };
    [manager POST:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobars/"
       parameters:parameters
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
          }];
```

ERROR LOG:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x7cd17260 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ce70b00> { URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobars/ } { status code: 400, headers {
    Allow = "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Wed, 03 Dec 2014 13:21:45 GMT";
    Server = "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.8";
    Vary = "Accept, Cookie";
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobars/, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226765 6f5f6c6f 63617469 6f6e223a 205b2244 69657365 73204665 6c642069 7374207a 77696e67 656e6420 6572666f 72646572 6c696368 2e225d7d>}
```

Django Server Logs: `[03/Dec/2014 14:21:45] "POST /foobars/ HTTP/1.1" 400 60`

What I'm doing wrong here? I guess it's something with the Serializer, but I'm not sure.

EDIT: Now I was trying this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSDictionary *newGeopoint = @{
                                 @"latitude": @"51.1205530",
                                 @"longitude": @"9.6444050"
                                 };
    [manager POST:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/geopoints/"
       parameters:newGeopoint
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *responseObject)
    {
        NSDictionary *newFooBar = @{
                                    @"geo_location":responseObject,
                                    @"geo_fence": @"SOMEWHERE"
                                    };
        [manager POST:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobars/"
           parameters:newFooBar
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                  NSLog(@"responseObject %@", responseObject);
              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"NewFooBarERROR: %@", error);
              }];

    }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"newGeopointERROR: %@", error);
    }];
```

But I get the same error message :/

```
2014-12-04 09:47:23.828 ShoutPreView[1853:276181] NewFooBarERROR: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x79f90610 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7b08d360> { URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobars/ } { status code: 400, headers {
    Allow = "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Thu, 04 Dec 2014 08:47:23 GMT";
    Server = "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.8";
    Vary = "Accept, Cookie";
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobars/, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226765 6f5f6c6f 63617469 6f6e223a 205b2244 69657365 73204665 6c642069 7374207a 77696e67 656e6420 6572666f 72646572 6c696368 2e225d7d>}
```

EDIT USING DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK 3.0:
I have updated django rest framework to 3.0.
On my Website in the API View, there a now two field in FooBar (one for long. other for lat.) 
When I'm trying to POST over Website/APIView I get the Error:

```
IntegrityError at /foobars/
NOT NULL constraint failed: restServer_foobar.geo_location_id
```

I have deleted my Database and maked a new one. Same Error :/

Serializer:

```
class GeopointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Geopoint
        fields = ('id', 'latitude', 'longitude')

class FooBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    geo_location = GeopointSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = FooBar
        fields = ('id', 'geo_location', 'geo_fence', 'registered', 'last_login')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        geo_location_data = validated_data.pop('geo_location')
        foobar = FooBar.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Geopoint.objects.create(FooBar=foobar, **geo_location_data)
        return foobar
```

**SOLVED**
It was a after updating to django-restframework-3.0 a problem with AFNetworking.

Here is my Objective-C code.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    NSDictionary *foobarparams = @ {@"geo_location" :@{
                                                       @"latitude":@997,
                                                       @"longitude":@997
                                                       }, @"geo_fence" :@"Frankfurt" };


    [manager POST:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobars/" parameters:foobarparams
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    }
          failure:
     ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model FooBar has a ForeignKey field, you added a serializerfield in FooBarSerializer but this is not enough to create a new FooBar + a new Geopoint.

Django Rest Framework (2.4.x) does not support at the moment a ModelSerializer subclass with writable nested serializer (like the one you are trying to implement). It is an ongoing task, see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#writable-nested-serialization

What I would recommend is either :

- perform 2 requests, one to create a geopoint, one to create a FooBar (with the id of your newly created geopoint) - (dirty !, but fast to implement)
- modify your serializer (FooBarSerializer) to subclass serializers.Serializer and override behavior when deserializing your FooBar object, see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

EDIT:

Change your request @"geo_location":responseObject, with the key value (i.e. an integer). It could be responseObject.pk

Comment: NSInteger idOfGeolocaton = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
        NSNumber *pk = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:idOfGeolocaton];
        NSDictionary *newFooBar = @{
                                    @"geo_location":pk,
                                    @"geo_fence": @"SOMEWHERE"
                                    };   .......  nothing changed :/